# Why COUNT(*) on linked server is inaccurate?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have two SQL Servers, separate hardware boxes.
Server A:
 Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP3-GDR) (KB3194721) - 11.0.6248.0 (X64) 
    Sep 23 2016 15:49:43 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor).

Server B:
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 (SP4) (KB4018073) - 11.0.7001.0 (X64) 
    Aug 15 2017 10:23:29 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

I recently deleted all the rows in one table from Server A and copied the rows from Server B using the import wizard.

When I execute these COUNT(*) queries from Server A, I get the identical result for each query, 200,703 rows.

```
select count(*) from dbo.thisTable

select count(*) from [Server B].[mydb].[dbo].[thisTable]
```

But if I exec the second COUNT(*)  on Server B, it tells me I have 196,420 rows.

The copy wizard threw no errors.  Any idea what happened?

Comment: Are the columns nullable in each table and do they have nulls? Are both schemas identical including indexes? Check your query plan to see how the count is actually executed; which index or column was used. Quite likely you're dealing with nulls in one of the counts where it's not counted.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the things that could describe a different count on the same table (remote or not) are:

- query a different table without knowing it due to default schema
- query at a different time, where data changes have happened in the meantime
- query with different isolation semantics (e.g. using `NOLOCK` or snapshot during data changes)
- query a table with row-level security
- query a view with filtering of any kind
- query a synonym that actually points to a different object

Other explanations are usually that they are *not* the same table. Does server B have a loopback linked server to server B? Or did you execute a slightly *different* query on server B? Is it possible it was in a different database, or that the linked server on server A might be pointing at something else?